# Several fallback implementations for some methods of a Hystrix-wrapped Feign client ( Spring Cloud Camden)

Tags: spring-cloud, hystrix, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-feign

We started to use Hystrix-wrapped `@FeignClient` with Spring Cloud Camden. It is easy to provide fallbacks using the fallback and fallbackFactory properties of the annotation, but we have some special needs.

We want to provide fallbacks only for specific methods of the Feign client. And we want to be able to provide different fallback implementations for the same Feign client method, depending on the use-case that is invoking.

But we don't want to give up on having Hystrix by default. It would be better to not have to annotate every method with `@HystrixCommand`.

Using `@HystrixCommand` provides a lot of flexibility, but I've observed that combining `@HystrixCommand` and wrapped clients results in Hystrix creating 2 thread pools: one for the class that defines the `@HystrixCommand` annotated methods and another for the Feign wrapped client.

The pool defined by the `@HystrixCommand` delegates the calls to the thread pool that wraps the Feign client. That is not optimal. A direct consequence is that we have duplicated circuit breakers, we might have to configure the timeouts twice, etc.  And I don't know if that can work fine or it can cause  troubles in production.

I have been looking for some days for what would be the best way to implement that but I don't think I found a good solution. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can disable feigns hystrix integration

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer @spncergibbb. I was trying to avoid that, to be able to have hystrix by default for all the methods. 

Would there be a problem Using `@HystrixCommand` and `@FeignClient` as I mentioned?

Comment: `@HystrixCommand` on a feign client is untested.